# Eigenvalues of $I - A^TB$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Is there a nice formula for the eigenvalues of $I-AB^T$ where $A$ and $B$ are matrices.

For instance, in the case where $A$ and $B$ are vectors, there are $n-1$ eigenvalues with value $1$ and a single eigenvalue with value $B^TA$

Answer (score 1):

$|\lambda I_m-AB|=\lambda^{m-n}|\lambda I_n-BA|$,where $A$ is a $m\times n$ matrix and $B$ is a $n \times m$ matrix and $m \ge n$.

It can be proved by the order-reducing formula.

Comment: To prove it ,you may construct a matrix and use the order-reducing formula,or canonical form,or perturbation method.The last one worth considering. But the second one is much more easier.

Comment: on account to my language barrier, I have trouble calling the definite name of the second method.You just use invertible matrix $P$ and $Q$,to make A as ($I_r$,$O$),($O,O$)

Comment: If you are confused about any one of the method, welcome to ask me. But my answer might be late,to be honest.

Comment: Thanks a lot. To verify the answer: do you mean that it has n-m zero eigenvalues and the rest are the eigenvalues of $B^TA$?

Comment: Actually, the rest are the eigenvalues of $BA^T$ as your denotation,the eigenvalues of $B^T A$ are same as those of     $A^T B$ Because $C^T \sim C$. you say you want to find a easy way to calculate.First, we need that $BA^T$ is easier than $A^TB$. Then we use the theorem that the eigenvalues of $f(A)$ are $f(\lambda_i)$.

Comment: I'm not sure about your denotation, but it seems to me that $A^T B$ is $n \times n$, as well as $B^T A$. This is not gonna simplify you calculation. So I think it's just your  mistake about denotation. $B^T A$ is not a value.

Comment: $A$ and $B$ can be thought of $n\times m$ matrices with $m<n$

Comment: I know what you are talking about.In fact, your title is not in correspondence to the body of question. So I'd say that your last claim is absolutely right.

Answer (score 0):

Since eigenvalues $\lambda$ of a matrix $M$ are solutions to $\left| M - \lambda I \right| = 0$, eigenvalues of $I-AB^T$ are solutions to

$$
\left| I - AB^T - \lambda I \right| = - \left| AB^T - (1 - \lambda) I \right| = 0,
$$

i.e. each eigenvalue $\lambda$ is equal to $1 - \mu$, where $\mu$ is some eigenvalue of $AB^T$. And since $AB^T v = (B \cdot v) A$ is proportional to $A$ for any vector $v$, the only eigenvalue of $AB^T$ is $A$ itself with eigenvalue $B \cdot A$. [Note -- the question originally stated that A and B were vectors].

Comment: Thanks for your reply @jwimberley. What does the notation $B\cdot v$ means? $B$ is a matrix

Comment: @Morad Sorry, your question originally said that A and B were vectors.

Comment: No, I gave an example what happens in the vector case. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Well, if $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary matrices, $I-AB^T$ is arbitrary too, so there's nothing special about its eigenvalues. I.e. I can take any matrix $M$ and set $A=I-M$ and $B=I$ so that $I-AB^T = M$.

Comment: Think of $A$ and $B$ as matrices with lower dimension than the $I$. For instance, $I = I_{n\times n}$ and $A,B$ have dimensions $n \times 2$ with $n>2$